# What's up with the magic rows when accessing float indexes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a":[11, 11, 22],
        "i":[1081., 1071., 22.],
    },
)
df = df.set_index("i")
# df.index = df.set_index("i").astype(int)
print df.loc[[-99999999]]
```

Gets:

```
            a
i            
-99999999 NaN
```

However, if the index is more sensibly populated with ints, then Pandas sensibly complains with:

```
KeyError: u'None of [[-99999999]] are in the [index]'
```

What's up with this? Why are float and int indexes behaving differently and what's the rationale for inventing magic rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.  A `KeyError` should be raised when using `.loc[list-of-labels]` if none of the labels are present.  Per the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated), `.loc[list-of-labels]` will raise in the future if *any* labels are missing.

Comment: Had to have been, although I don't have enough authority to proclaim that a bug is a bug. :-)